# React Native - Flat list scrolling is not working in Pan Responder

Tags: react-native, scroll, react-native-flatlist

React Native, Using PanResponder View as a parent and having flatlist as a child of the view, without PanResponder, flatlist scrolling is working fine but with PanResponder, flatlist scrolling is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I dont find proper solution, but workaround is wrap the flatlist items in `TouchableOpacity` , it will make flatlist scrollable. 
If you don't like TouchableOpacity's opacity then you can set `activeOpacity` to 1.

Example:

```js
<View {...this.gestureHandlers.panHandlers} style={styles.container}>
  <FlatList
    horizontal={true}
    data={this.state.FlatlistData}
    renderItem={({ item }) => {
      return (
        <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={1} style={styles.itemsStyle}>
          {/* Your core view here */}
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )
    }}
  />
</View>
```